# database design for song position under play-list

Tags: sql-server, database-design, schema, table

I have a music streaming application where I have playlists. Each playlist has maximum 100 songs. I have a mapping table called PlaylistSongMapping which has the following schema

```
+------+------------+--------+
|SongId| PlaylistId |Position|
+------+------------+--------+
|   1  |     10     |    2   |
|   2  |     10     |    1   |
|   3  |     10     |    3   | 
|   5  |     10     |    4   | 
|   6  |     11     |    1   |
+------+------------+--------+
```

The position of each song inside playlist is managed using the Position column. Inside the playlist I need the order change functionality. The current logic is to update Position column. The problem is if i need to move the song with SongId: 3 to first position I need to update rows of SongId 1,2,3. This number would be a big one when playlist has more number of songs. Is there a better logic so that number of update queries are very minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Position` field you can use a field as `LastSongId` where you can add the `SongId` of the previous song in the play list.

So when you want to change you order you only need to update only three rows.

The first row: Your song with new order

The second row / the third row: The song before and after your your changed position song

Your new schema:

```
+------+------------+----------+
|SongId| PlaylistId |LastSongId|
+------+------------+----------+
|   1  |     10     |    NULL  |
|   2  |     10     |    1     |
|   3  |     10     |    2     | 
|   5  |     10     |    3     | 
|   6  |     11     |    NULL  |
+------+------------+----------+
```

If you change the SongId 3 as position 1, you'll have:

```
+------+------------+----------+
|SongId| PlaylistId |LastSongId|
+------+------------+----------+
|   1  |     10     |    3     |
|   2  |     10     |    1     |
|   3  |     10     |    NULL  | 
|   5  |     10     |    2     | 
|   6  |     11     |    NULL  |
+------+------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you leave gaps one way or another, you can postpone a massive update until later. Using an integer with gaps:

```
-- init
update PlaylistSongMapping set Position = 10000 * position;

-- move songId = 3 to first position
update PlaylistSongMapping set Position = 5000 
where SongId = 3
  and PlaylistId = 10;
```

Another option is to use a decimal, but the idea remains the same.

Yet another option is to add a secondary order attribute:

```
ALTER TABLE PlaylistSongMapping
    ADD COLUMN Position_secondary INT DEFAULT 1000 NOT NULL;

-- move songId = 3 to first position
update PlaylistSongMapping 
    set Position = 1
      , Position_secondary = 500  
where SongId = 3
  and PlaylistId = 10;

-- Get songs in order:
select * from PlaylistSongMapping
order by PlaylistId, Position, Position_secondary
```